# How can I use React's prop-types package to check for a specific type of element?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'd like to use prop-types to check for specifically an `img` or `svg` element (at the top level). How would I use the library to do that check or to create a custom prop type to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `type` attribute of the JSX object to check what HTML element is being passed through.

Child component

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { passedElement } = this.props;

        return (
            {passedElement}
        );
    }
}

SomeComponent.propTypes = {
    passedElement: PropTypes.shape({
        type: PropTypes.oneOf(['img', 'svg']),
    }),
};
```

Parent component

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        // Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `passedElement.type` of value `div` supplied to `SomeComponent`, expected one of ["img","svg"].
        return <SomeComponent passedElement={<div></div>} />

        // No error, renders as expected
        return <SomeComponent passedElement={<img />} />
    }
}
```